# AAPT.exe crashed after added the Aursama kernal in Project

Tags: android, eclipse, aapt, aurasma

I am trying to integrate Aurasma kernal with my android application. I followed the instructions as given in the http://www.aurasma.com/partners/support/Aurasma%20Kernel%20Guidelines.pdf. The build fails with aapt.exe crashing in the pre-compilation phase.

The manifest file has the settings as - minSDKversion: 8 targetSDKversion: 14

Following are the libraries in my application:

android-support-v4.jar
facebookSDK.jar
FlurryAgent.jar
httpclient-4.1.2.jar
httpcore-4.1.2.jar
httpmime-4.1.2.jar
apache-mime4j-core-0.7.jar
myttjson-1.7.1.jar
scribe-1.1.0.jar
trace.jar

I found httpmime-4.11.jar and apache-mime4j-0.6.1.jar in aurasma kernal build path. Because of this, I got an error that there are multiple dex files. I removed these jars from my application's build path. The issue of multiple dex files is resolved, but Aapt crash remains.

Assuming that the problem could be limited to the Windows version of Aapt, I tried it on a Mac. After nearly the same time and steps, Aapt terminated with an error code 139.

i have changed the Windows > Preference > Andriod > Build > Output to Normal and Verbose but the Aapt crash remains.

Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Why you have exe file? In Android you have to use apk file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have resolved the problem,in my project style.xml for some of the styles definitions have android:id , this causes the aapt crash, after i removed this its working fine.